# How to zip files with a specific name from branch directory that are older than 57 days?

Tags: zip

I have a linux query, and I was wondering if you might know a way to string multiple commands into one with this criteria:

1. Find files, from a branch directory, called gec_log_* - older than 57 days (+57)
2. gzip (we have only installed gzip) these files

I know how to do both individually

1. find /var/loop/hj/date -name "generic_log_*" -type f -mtime +57
2. gzip gec_log_*

I have tried pipeline, but that hasn't worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your "find" command in point 1 is missing the action part :) (so it uses the default action of `-print`). Add an action to gzip the found files, like this:

`find find /var/loop/hj/date -name "generic_log_*" -type f -mtime +57 -exec gzip {} \;`

This will only gzip the files, without listing them. If you want to both list the files and gzip them, you can combine both actions like this:

`find /find /var/loop/hj/date -name "generic_log_*" -type f -mtime +57 -print -exec gzip {} \;`